# Call pushViewController from external class?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

I'm new to IOS7 and i am struggling to call `pushViewController`.

First i have `UINavigationController` as a root view controller i have `UICollectionViewController`.

In this `UICollectionViewController` i have also register `UICollectionViewCell` class

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[MYProductCell class]
   forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"product"];
```

I am trying to `pushViewController` width detail view based on user action in the cell.

I have NO problems by using

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *product = self.products[indexPath.row];

    TXDetailProductController *detailView = [[TXDetailProductController alloc] init];
     detailView.product = product;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];

}
```

But I want to call pushViewController:detailView from `UICollectionViewCell` class based on User action.

Can someone give me directions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: hold on.. i'm editing my answer to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send a message.

In your viewDidLoad you could set up a message listener:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pushDetailView:) name:@"pushDetailView" object:nil];
```

Then add a method:

```
    -(void) pushDetailView:(id)sender
    {
        // do your pushViewController
    }
```

Then in your `UICollectionViewCell` when you need to push the view do:

```
    NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"pushDetailView" object:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
```

The listener should receive that notification and call the `pushDetailView` which will push the view.  You might need some error checking in there also.

You might need to pass information to the method so you know what to push.  You can put the information in an object and send it with the message.  Something like:

```
    NSNumber *indexPathRow = [NSNumber numberWithInt: indexPath.row];
    NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"pushDetailView" indexPathRow object:indexPathRow];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
```

Then on the receiver class you pull that info out of the notification's object:

```
    -(void) pushDetailView:(NSNotification*)note
    {
        NSNumber indexPathRow = [note object];
        NSDictionary *product = self.products[[indexPathRow intValue]];
        // and on with your pushViewController code
    }
```

Again error checking in there also.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if an NSNumber can be a notification object or if it has to be converted to an NSString.  It's possible that your NSIndexPath can be the object directly without conversation.  I'd try that first.

Comment: God bless you! It works! Smooth as silk. Your edit comes just on time, when i start researching how to pass arguments with NSNotification. But now your answer is complete! Thanks once again.

Comment: So were you able to send the NSIndexPath directly as the object?

Comment: Yeah. From cell directly: NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"pushDetailView" object:self.product];